# Change category product listing layout on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am working on `Magento ver. 1.9.0.1`. there is request from our executives in our company that the `product listing page` for certain category should just display only the `name` and `SKU` with `ADD TO CART button` on the category page. that is, *eliminate the showing of image and short description to have maximum number of product on single page*:

eg: http://www.sciencellonline.com/products-services/media/specialty/low-serum.html

I know there is a way to change the layout at the following location, I tried several solution in multiple different places but couldn't fix, i.e. `[Category Edit Page] > Custom Design > Page Layout`

SOLUTION BELOW:
I end up changing the default category product listing for all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new theme, where you only change the template for product listing and make some of the categories use that theme from the `Design` tab on the category add/edit form.